# displaying multiple tables present in the user tables

Tags: sql, plsql

We have to display the data present in all the tables that are in user_tables . my code is

```
DECLARE
name varchar2(50);
s_query varchar2(500);
cursor c_demo is select table_name from    user_tables;
BEGIN
open c_demo;
loop
fetch c_demo into name;
EXIT WHEN c_demo%notfound;
select * into s_query from @name; 
dbms_output.put_line(s_query);
end loop;
close c_demo;
end;
```

But it is showing error that table is missing

Answer (score 0):

you can execute dynamic SQL like this :

1.Define a var

```
     sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
```

2. build query

   ```
    sql_stmt := 'select * from '||name;
   ```
3. Exceute Statement:

   ```
   for r in sql_stmt
   loop
   //perfom operation on data

   end loop;
   ```

Comment: Its good idea but i have an issue with it ... for 'SQL_stmt' data type should be of %rowtype , as we have multiple tables how can we implement it

Comment: sql_stmt will always be VARCHAR2 as it contains dynamic sql statement. You can user r.columnName to access columns inside loop

Comment: If I don't know the column name then how should I access them